# Unusable scheduling jitter using Web Audio API, Cordova and Crosswalk

Tags: android, cordova, audio, web-audio-api, crosswalk-runtime

I have written a scheduler (based on the [A Tale of Two Clocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/) article) which runs absolutely fine on the desktop browser. However, the Android Cordova app (Redmi Note 4G running Kitkat 4.4.4) has so much jitter as to be unusable.

The test bed is a metronome playing back a short oscillator tone on the click using the Web Audio API. I am using the Crosswalk browser plugin to obtain Web Audio support.

Even with modest scheduling and look ahead values (500ms and 250ms), the notes are noticeably out of time. I have tried shutting down all other apps but I am new to app development so am at a loss as to what the source of the jitter is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Old android has huge audio latency and is completely unusable for audio applications even if you were making a native app. In Lollipop it should be much better.

Comment: I'm wondering same thing, running an LG K7 with Android 5.1.1. I get just enough jitter that cannot get a steady metronome even with nothing else running. The thing is, there seems to be a pattern to the jitter, like every downbeat of the measure, making me crazy thinking its my code. However it runs perfectly smoothly on desktop...

Comment: Update: After much headbanging, I discovered the issue was that I was using Date objects to determine the age of user inputs, and this was spiking the garbage collector about once every 2 seconds, which was hogging the CPU and adding jitter. By converting code to instead use AudioContext.currentTime, I've been able to eliminate audible jitter.